# IBM Cloud Code Engine: Stateful Apps and Sticky Sessions, Scaling Issues

Tags: ibm-cloud, stateful, ibm-cloud-code-engine

My first post on stackoverflow; here goes!

I just discovered IBM Code Engine and am excited to try it out! I tried deploying a docker image of mine this weekend, though I'm having some issues with scaling. Before getting to the scaling issues I have some questions about IBM Cloud Code Engine in general, with my interactive application in mind:

1. **Stateful Applications:** The application I'd like to deploy is stateful. Does IBM Cloud Code Engine support stateful apps out of the box?
2. **Sticky Sessions:** Since my application is stateful, the goal is to have a user and all their associated actions **stay within the same container.** E.g., if a user is in `container 1` and clicks a button that executes server-side code **I would not want** that code executed in `container 2`; it should be in `container 1`. Does IBM Cloud Code Engine support this out of the box?
3. **Ephemeral Storage:** I see in the documentation that ephemeral storage (i.e., disk space) can be set, though I do not see the ability to modify this in the console.  Am I missing something?  Alternatively, does more vCPU & memory imply more disk?  I personally prefer the CLI for the container registry, and the console for code engine itself.

Note that I have these questions whether concurrency per instance is 1 or more users.

**Notes on scaling:**
I successfully deployed my application and it looked as expected.  However, as the only user I saw multiple instances running rather than one (2, sometimes 3 instances). When I opened another browser and logged in as another user the same thing happened.  Double or triple the instances needed were running.  Can someone advise?  Going back to my questions above, my hope is that interacting with the app does not trigger additional instances.

I can provide a simple Dockerfile and app code if helpful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Generally speaking the answer is yes, although it depends how you define stateful and where you store the state. Example: storing the state in an COS/S3 bucket is possible, storing it in an NFS mount not at the moment
2. Unfortunately no. The underlying Knative OSS technology does not support sticky sessions yet, although the open source community is working on it, so it might be coming.
3. This is not currently supported in the UI, but in the CLI you can specify `ibmcloud ce app create --ephemeral-storage` as a param
4. Scaling: That depends on how you have defined your scaling criteria. When you create your app, in the `Runtime settings` section you can specify a concurrency value. That determines the value how many threads/requests one instance will process in parallel. If the value is set to 1, and you have three browser tabs open sending requests, Code engine will scale up to (at least) three instances (e.g. when the scale target is 70% of compute capacity, we’d spin up to 4).  If the value is set to 100, one instance will handle 100 parallel requests and the scale out will only occur if you get 101 requests. It is independent of how many users send these requests.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and definitive clarifications; that makes sense. Quick follow-up on (2), as I'm concerned about app runtime and responsiveness if app state resides in a bucket. If **min instances = 0** and **max instances = 1** would app states on the server work in a limited fashion? (including using the local file system) I.e. set the instance vCPU and memory to handle estimated request volume. In such a setup is it safe to say all requests remain in the same container? If so, there are still benefits given the scale to 0 functionality so one only pays when the app is running.

Comment: That would only be true if your container practically never scales down at the moment. If it scales down, that particular container stays around for some TIMEOUT value, but is then discarded. When a new request arrives after that, the container will get re-created from scratch and thus will lose the state information in the file system, as it would get a new ephemeral file system then.

Comment: This tutorial shows how to deploy a database-backed web app to Code Engines. Users have to authenticate and that state is stored in session cookies. All other information is kept in the database. I am running it with scale-to-zero https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/solution-tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-serverless-github-traffic-analytics

Comment: To clarify, I am only concerned about state data preservation (and not mixing requests) **during a request.** I have persistent storage in a remote bucket, and the plan is to pull state info upon app load (when a connection is made), and periodically save to that bucket throughout a session. Therefore, state info is not lost and will be pulled again next time that user's session begins (I have authentication). Is it safe to say if min instances = 0 & max instances = 1 then all requests remain in the same container, the file system can be used, & scale=0 when there are 0 requests?